# Android: I want to create a new file in sdcard when the apk is installing

Tags: android

I want to create a new file in sdcard when ***the apk is installing***...
How or where should I code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can not do that. That would introduce all kinds of security concerns. As Ken Y -N said in his answer, the best thing to do would be to detect the first time that your app is opened, and do something there.

Here's an activity class to do this:

```
public class StartupChoiceActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = StartupChoiceActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(!mPrefs.getBoolean("has_started_before", false)) {
            // Do what ever you want to do the first time the app is run

        } else {
            //Remember our choice for next time
            mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("has_started_before", true).commit();
            Log.i(TAG, "We've already started the app at least once");
        }

        //Do what ever we want to do on a normal startup. This is pretty much always mean starting a new activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MyNormalFirstActivity.class);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The only other thing you need to do is make sure this activity is set as your 'Startup' activity in the AndroidManifest.xml. You can do this by putting this code inside your application tag:

```
<activity android:name=".StartupChoiceActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that; such a feature would be a good way of getting trojans to propagate, for instance.

Just check for the first run of your program and do the initialisation there.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I wanna know if there is someway to do that, and how to get it?